# Keeping layout view pixels and increasing the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'll show you a picture for easy explanation.

[image]

Assuming that the size of the smartphone screen is 1920x1080.

In general, a view of 512x512 is shown in (1).

However, I want to fill the screen of the smartphone by keeping 512x512 pixels like (2).

Of course the picture quality will fall but it does not matter!

How should I do it?

Note that this is not fitCenter in ImageView.
This is a question about layout.

---

[image]

In this figure, the 2560x1440 is the actual smartphone screen size.

And I set the layout and view class to the size I want (160dp * 92dp -> 640px * 368px).

I want to keep the quality of the view class at 160dp * 92dp while filling the screen of the smartphone.

Comment: Set `layout_width` and `layout_height` to `match_parent`?

Comment: @akash93
Hello.
Please check my edited question.

Comment: Is it just for a particular imageview or is it for any view in general?

Comment: I want to process multiple frames coming through the camera, not just a single image.

Comment: Still unclear as to what you're trying to achieve.. As per the edit you've manually set the height and width as 160x92dp and you expect it to show up fullscreen?

Comment: Yes. I want to set it to 160x92dp and it will come out full screen on my smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

and `android:layout_width="match_parent"`.

Comment: I think you read the question backwards-  I think he wants it full screen

Comment: @Abhriya Roy 
Hello.
As you say, you will look like Figure (1).
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @GabeSechan
Hello.
Yes. You are right.
I want full screen :)